# How to get popup on another popup in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, popup

I tried to get a popup in a popup, but it failed to work.

I have one page where if you click on the img's you get a popup. But when your in the popup, another popup I wanna have opened with the  link and go back and then close it. My page is on this page: [https://85377.ict-lab.nl/KDMOBILE1/Mobile1/TinyLivin'/Homepage.html](https://85377.ict-lab.nl/KDMOBILE1/Mobile1/TinyLivin%27/Homepage.html) .

Its in Dutch but it goes about the popup in popup section. You probably won't get a loaded screen here, because you don't have the pics and I do.

Do i have to add extra component or another page that has a data-rel to a new popup? I also have my code here. I'm not experienced in diffucult Javascript query, so I probably won't understand that.

I disabled my container as I don't need it. There is also a mobile query for mobile. On my phone everything looks fine.

I **JUST** need to get popup in popup in the html divs. I here soon if you know :)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mobilemenu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            html{
                height: 1000px;
            }

            #vak1geheel{
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                border: solid 1px;
                position: relative;
                left: 25%;
                background: #F85032;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg,  #F85032 0%, #F16F5C 50%, #F6290C 51%, #F02F17 71%, #E73827 100%);
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg,  #F85032 0%,#F16F5C 50%,#F6290C 51%,#F02F17 71%,#E73827 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(-90deg,  #F85032 0%,#F16F5C 50%,#F6290C 51%,#F02F17 71%,#E73827 100%);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#F85032', endColorstr='#E73827',GradientType=0 );
            }

            #welkomstinfo img{
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
            }

            #welkomstinfo h1{
                text-align: center;
                position: absolute;
                top: 215px;
                left: 70px;
                margin-left: 32.778125%;
                color: #33C7FF;
                font-size: 1.5em;
            }

            h2{
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 60px;
            }

            button{
                width: 74%;
                background-color: #33C7FF;
                border: none;
                height: 50px;
                margin-left: 13%;
                margin-right: 13%;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }

            button:hover{
                background-color: #000000;
                color: #33C7FF;
                border: none;
            }

            #footer1{
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                border: solid 1px;
                margin: 5px;
                background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #61C419, #61C419, #FFFF00, #F85032, #F85032);
            }

            @media all and (max-device-width: 460px){
                #vak1geheel{
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    border: solid 1px;
                    position: relative;
                    left: 0;
                    background: #F85032;
                    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg,  #F85032 0%, #F16F5C 50%, #F6290C 51%, #F02F17 71%, #E73827 100%);
                    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg,  #F85032 0%,#F16F5C 50%,#F6290C 51%,#F02F17 71%,#E73827 100%);
                    background: linear-gradient(-90deg,  #F85032 0%,#F16F5C 50%,#F6290C 51%,#F02F17 71%,#E73827 100%);
                    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#F85032', endColorstr='#E73827',GradientType=0 );
                }

                #welkomstinfo img{
                    width: 100%;
                    position: relative;
                }

                #welkomstinfo h1{
                    text-align: center;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 142px; /*top: 132px; h2*/
                    margin-left: 19%;
                    color: #33C7FF;
                }

                h2{
                    text-align: center;
                    margin-top: 60px;
                }


                button{
                    width: 74%;
                    background-color: #33C7FF;
                    border: none;
                    height: 50px;
                    margin-left: 13%;
                    margin-right: 13%;
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                    margin-top: 10px;
                }

                button:hover{
                    background-color: #000000;
                    color: #33C7FF;
                    border: none;
                }

                #footer1{
                    position: relative;
                    text-align: center;
                    border: solid 1px;
                    margin: 5px;
                    background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #61C419, #61C419, #FFFF00, #F85032, #F85032);
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pagina1" data-role="page" data-theme="b">

        <div id="vak1geheel">
            <!--<div class="container">
                 <nav>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a href="Homepage.html">Home</a></li>
                         <li><a href="Vervolgpagina1.html"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="Vervolgpagina2.html"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="Vervolgpagina3.html"></a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </nav>
            </div>-->

                <div id="welkomstinfo">
                    <img src="Welkomstimage.jpeg">
                    <h1>WELKOM!!</h1>
                </div>

            <div id="overzichtshuis1">
                <div class="popup-overlay">
                    <a href="#popup1" data-rel="popup"><img src="Tinylivinghouse1.jpg" style="width: 58%;
                    height: 12em; margin-left: 21%; margin-top: 2em"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="overzichtshuis2">
                <div class="popup-overlay">
                    <a href="#popup2" data-rel="popup"><img src="Tinylivinghouse2.jpg" style="width: 60%;
                     margin-left: 20%; height: 12em;"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer1">
                <p>Social media linkjes(Je kan er gewoon op klikken)</p>
                <img src="instagram-logo.png" width="45px" height="30px" onclick="window.location.href =
                'https://www.instagram.com/tinylivin/'">
                <img src="Reddit.png" width="30px" height="30px" onclick="window.location.href =
                'https://www.reddit.com/user/Tinylivin/'"><p><strong>Tel: +1 707-567-8659</strong></p>
            </div>
                <div id="popup1" data-role="popup" data-transistion="fade" style="width: auto; top: 0;"><br/>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 2em;">Tiny house 1</h2>
                    <a href="#"><img src="Tinylivinghouse1.jpg" style="width: 60%; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%;"></a>
                    <a href="#popup3" style="margin-left: 45.5%; margin-right: 45.5%;">Klik voor meer</a>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">40 m3</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Veluwe</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Geschikt voor gezin</p><br/>
                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p><br/>

                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
                    <a role="button" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete
                    ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-left">X</a>
                </div>

                <div id="popup2" data-role="popup" data-transistion="fade" style="width: auto; top: 0;"><br/>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 2em;">Tiny house 2</h2>
                    <a href="#"><img src="Tinylivinghouse2.jpg" style="width: 60%; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%;"></a>
                    <a href="#popup4" style="margin-left: 45.5%; margin-right: 45.5%;">Klik voor meer</a>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">22 m3</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Heemvaardse plassen</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Voor stelletjes</p><br/>
                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p><br/>

                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
                    <a role="button" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete
                    ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-left">X</a>
                </div>

                <div id="popup3" data-role="popup" style="width: auto; top: 0;"><br/>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 2em;">Tiny house 3</h2>
                    <a href="#"><img src="Tinylivinghouse2.jpg" style="width: 60%; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%;"></a>
                    <a href="#popup5" style="margin-left: 45.5%; margin-right: 45.5%;">Klik voor meer</a>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">22 m3</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Heemvaardse plassen</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Voor stelletjes</p><br/>
                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p><br/>

                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
                    <a role="button" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete
                    ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-left">X</a>
                </div>

                <div id="popup4" data-role="popup" style="width: auto; top: 0;"><br/>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 2em;">Tiny house 4</h2>
                    <a href="#"><img src="Tinylivinghouse2.jpg" style="width: 60%; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%;"></a>
                    <a href="#popup6" style="margin-left: 45.5%; margin-right: 45.5%;">Klik voor meer</a>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">22 m3</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Heemvaardse plassen</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Voor stelletjes</p><br/>
                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p><br/>

                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
                    <a role="button" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete
                    ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-left">X</a>
                </div>

                <div id="popup5" data-role="popup" style="width: auto; top: 0;"><br/>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 2em;">Tiny house 2</h2>
                    <a href="#"><img src="Tinylivinghouse2.jpg" style="width: 60%; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%;"></a>
                    <a href="#popup4" style="margin-left: 45.5%; margin-right: 45.5%;">Klik voor meer</a>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">22 m3</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Heemvaardse plassen</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Voor stelletjes</p><br/>
                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p><br/>

                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
                <a role="button" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete
                ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-left">X</a>
                </div>

                <div id="popup6" data-role="popup" style="width: auto; top: 0;"><br/>
                    <h2 style="font-size: 2em;">Tiny house 2</h2>
                    <a href="#"><img src="Tinylivinghouse2.jpg" style="width: 60%; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%;"></a>
                    <a href="#popup4" style="margin-left: 45.5%; margin-right: 45.5%;">Klik voor meer</a>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">22 m3</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Heemvaardse plassen</p>
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Voor stelletjes</p><br/>
                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p><br/>

                    <p style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 90%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum
                        dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor
                        sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                        amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
                    <a role="button" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete
                    ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-left">X</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/chained-popups-with-simpledialog2/

Comment: @deblocker alright lets check thx